# How can I delete values by column in a data frame?

Tags: r

I need to take abundance values by column without zeros, by this reason I used an empty list and a loop (for loop). When I delete [i] in the first line of my loop I get the desired result only in the column of total values (sum by an object), but in the way in which I learn to write them, I only obtain an undesired result.

```
set.seed(1000)

df <- data.frame(Category = sample(LETTERS[1:10]), 
                 Object = sample(letters[1:10]), 
                 A = sample(0:20, 10, rep = TRUE), 
                 B = sample(0:20, 10, rep = TRUE),
                 C = sample(0:20, 10, rep = TRUE))


sincero <- list()
for (i in colnames(df[ , 3:5])){
  sincero[i] = df[df[ , i] != 0, ]
  sincero
}
sincero
```

Comment: you need to `set.seed` using a number like `set.seed(234)`. Also, can you add your expected output for the example ?

Comment: I think you're asking for `df[rowSums(df[3:5] == 0) == 0, ]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4497050/alistaire thank you for your answer